# How to send a nodejs application by email?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I had to submit my nodejs application (written on JS and built with express generator) on the university network. 
As my supervisor tried to run the application it did not render on chrome. Instead it did not build the css. The versioning of node are correct so no version Problem. 
Please help!! :)

Comment: You either send it with install instructions (on exactly where to put things and what modules to install) or you send a compressed archive (with directory hierarchy) of everything that needs to be decompressed into the appropriate hierarchy or you put it into a whole installer that installs everything in the right place.  Those are basically your choices.

Comment: I don't know how you expect us to help you with a "did not build the CSS" problem when  you show us NOTHING of your project.  Not much we can do about that.  You have to debug what didn't end up in the right place and then figure out why.  We have absolutely no idea what you sent them or what they did to install things.  This question is very incomplete and not answerable by us as is.

Comment: I prefer to push it to bitbucket, which is private, and sending instructions as well for example:

1 - They must have Node installed on their machine => give a link for Node installation or any other frameworks they need to have installed on their system

2 - Send instructions on how to clone it from bitbucket then accessing the directory from terminal/bash/CMD and running necessary commands to install packages and run the application, that way you can at least guarantee that they have the same copy of the project and same environment

Comment: You need to zip it.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a ReadMe file, with step by step instructions? Might sound flippant but since I started to document stuff like, "git clone xxxxxx, cd xxxxxx, npm install, npm run dev" the number of issues i get from new team members has dropped.